# Bootstrap Nav Menu dropdown shows transparent/pink in IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transparency, internet-explorer-11

I have a strange issue using the Bootstrap nav menu. On IE11 the menu displays either with a pink background or semi-transparent highlighting text underneath (when viewed on a desktop i.e. Medium/Large width).

The strange thing is that this only happens on the dropdown menu items that are above the well containing the text (the first menu item behaves normally):

[image]

The markup is all pretty straighforward:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Time and Attendance<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Time and Attendance System</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Absence Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fire Roll Call</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Flexitime</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link to Payroll</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bradford Factor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Access Control</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Remote Workers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clocking in Options<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Clocking In Systems</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clocking In Machines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fingerprint Clocking Machines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hand Scanner Clocking Machines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proximity Clocking Machines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mobile Clocking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PC Based Clocking Software</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Job Costing<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Job Costing System</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Job Costing Software</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Job Costing Hardware</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Support<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Existing Customer Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Remote Desktop Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clear User Code</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#contact">About Us</a></li>

            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
```

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ogjfwtzh/)

Sometimes the pink is missing but the transparency issue it still there:
[image]

Comment: do you have any custom styles? because I do not see the problem in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I can replicate the issue using just that fiddle on IE11 Windows 8

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue in your fiddle. Any particular steps you take to trigger the problem?

Comment: that's what I see on IE11 win7 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32989095/screenshots/ie11-win7.JPG

Comment: Try hovering over the menu items. Sometimes it is not transparent (but still pink) othertimes the dropdown items stay highlighted when the hover is moved to another item. The issue only occurs on menu items that are over text one the page

Comment: works good for me, so this might be a win8 specific problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked this down to being an issue when `anchor` tags are inside or over the top of a `well`.

In IE the box-shadow was interferring with the background colour.

I added a custom rule for a `well` that removes this and it seems to cure it.

[Fiddle with fix](http://jsfiddle.net/ssaaed5y/1/)

Not sure if there is a more elegant workaround?

```
.well{
    box-shadow:none; /* Fixes transparent hover issue on links with IE */
}
```